# How to implement multi-inheritance in OOP?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

What is the best solution for situation:

```
class Person
...
class Student extends Person
...  
class Employee extends Person
...
class Visitor extends Person
...
```

And some person is employee and student, for example.
Classical  approach of inheritance isn't good solution.

I can use delegation pattern:

```
User {
   Person p.
   Collection<Role> roles; 
}
```

And All classes : Student, Employee, Visitor - will implement Role interface or class.

Is it a good solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Objects can't change their types, but people can change their roles. So the answer should be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the delegation pattern you suggest is a good idea. It has a lot of advantages over multiple inheritance:

1. It is supported by every language; multiple inheritance support differs from language to language and your language of choice might even have none at all.
2. The roles of a person do not have to be known at compile time.
3. You can adjust the roles at run time! A person may quit being a student or enrole as a student. Easy case with delegation, impossible with multiple inheritance
4. No combinatorical explosion: Consider you have ten roles. If any combination of roles was possible, you would need 2^10 = 1024 classes. Have fun with that.

So, stick to the delegation! Delegation is a wonderful thing and the answer to many questions in OOP :).